# UserControl conditional validation approach?

Tags: asp.net, validation, architecture, page-lifecycle

I have a custom UserControl which contains several TextBoxes with Validators. One TextBox with corresponding Validator is optional based on a CheckBox. Pseudo:

**My Control.ascx**:

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtAddress" />
<asp:Validator id="valAddress" />

<asp:CheckBox id="condition" />
<asp:TextBox id="txtConditional" />
<asp:Validator id="valConditional" ValidationGroup="ConditionalGroup" />
```

**My Control.ascx.cs**

```
public void Validate() {
    if(condition.Checked) {
        Page.Validate("ConditionalGroup");
    }
}
```

I also have a page which basically looks like this:

**Page.aspx**

```
<my:Control id="myControl" />

<asp:Button onClick="doPost" />
```

**Page.aspx.cs**

```
protected void doPost(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    myControl.Validate(); //This feels wrong

    if(Page.IsValid) {
        //go
    }
}
```

This all works, however I would like to take the `myControl.Validate()` line out of the `Page.aspx.cs` and put it in the `My Control.ascx.cs`. Putting it in the `Page_Load` of the control is not an option because the `conditional` checkbox value is always `false`. There is no event available **after** `Page_Load` and **before** the `doPost` click handler is fired...

**It feels wrong to call the custom `Validate` function on the `Page` where I think it should belong somewhere in the `UserControl`. Is it true that this is architecturally wrong? Is there another solution for this maybe by using an event handler?**

Comment: The events on a child control executes after the page (exception is the init phase).  So the control's page_load event is after the page's page_load and before the page's control events (e.g. doPost).  Note: this does not help you with your specific issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try by enabling the validator only if the user checks on the check box. And disable the validator if the unchecks it. This has to be done in the user control. It can be done in the client side or in the server side. In this way, the page would validate all the validators that are enabled for the page.